# Is there any functional difference between .bashrc and .bash_rc?

Tags: bash, shell

Is there any difference (functionality) between `.bashrc` and `.bash_rc` other than the underscore in the filename? Most of the webpages that I visit say `.bashrc` but the file in my Mac happens to be named `.bash_rc`. (I did create the file but I forgot the origin).

Comment: Inasmuch as this is a question about configuring your shell, as opposed to a question about software development, it's outside of StackOverflow's topical scope. Consider [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). And also consider a quick check of the man page before asking questions here -- reading the INVOCATION section of `man bash` would have covered this in detail.

Comment: Even in the man file only _.bashrc_ is mentioned. If you google ".bash_rc" (with quotes) you do get results, but nothing from documentation side, so I  have decided to ask.

Comment: See chepner's comments -- `.bash_profile` isn't the only file that's potentially implicated in sourcing `.bash_rc`, but whatever you *do* have doing that, it's not something that came with bash.

Comment: By the way, silly question, but are you sure that your `.bashrc` and `.bash_rc` aren't linked to each other (be that hardlinked or symlinked)?

Comment: No it's not a symbolic link.

Comment: Yes, even in the man page only `~/.bashrc` is mentioned, **because `.bash_rc` isn't a thing that bash knows or cares about**. By not mentioning `.bash_rc`, the documentation is answering that question. Grepping the source code or reading the string table from the compiled executable answers it even more authoritatively.

Comment: ...and did you check if it's a hardlink? (And is there a reason you aren't answering the question about what you get from `bash -x` with a PS4 that directs it to log the name of the files it's getting its commands from?)

Comment: I did a `ls -lla`, it did not give any info regarding links. I think it shows both soft and hard links.

Comment: Checking for hardlinks requires comparing inode numbers, since all a hardlink *is* is having more than one directory entry pointing to the same inode. It's an expensive operation (means you need to store every inode you've previously seen in memory and compare against that list or hash table), and not something `ls` does by default.

Comment: Its not a hardlink too, got the inode number(`ls -ai`) and used `find . -inum`. It only returned 1 file.

Comment: *nod*. The reason I was theorizing that it could be a hardlink was the assertion that code in it was actually being run on (non-login) shell startup; one possibility was that it could also exist under a different name that _was_ being sourced. Since it wasn't actually being run at shell startup at all, that entire line of inquiry was mooted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.bash_rc` has no special meaning to bash whatsoever: Unless you've gone out of your way to configure your shell to read it, its presence will have no effect.

Check that it isn't referenced by the `ENV` environment variable, and consider using:

```
PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO}+' bash -ix
```

...to track every line run during shell invocation, logged next to the filename and line number it came from; you can thusly identify exactly what's causing any given line to be executed by tracing upward from same.

Comment: but all the aliases I have added in _.bash\_rc_ file work in terminal and my _.bash\_profile_ doesn't have the word _.bash\_rc_ in it.

It actually has 
`if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi`

Comment: `/etc/profile` also runs before `.bash_profile`; it (or a file that it causes to be sourced) may be sourcing `~/.bash_rc`. Run `bash -x` and `bash -lx` to see exactly what gets executed while an interactive and a login shell starts up.

Comment: @chepner, excellent advice -- amended appropriately, but with a PS4 including filename and line number so the OP can trace upwards from the first place `.bash_rc` content is seen to be running to the parent command sourcing or otherwise invoking same.

Comment: _/etc/profile_ checks for _/etc/bashrc_ and that in turn checks for /etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal and all these don't have _bash\_rc_ .

Comment: @Gwynbleidd, we gave you a command that'll do all the tracing for you automatically. Tried it yet?

Comment: ran that, got this:
`:::0+history -a
:::0+history -c
:::0+history -r
:::0+history -a
:::0+history -c
:::0+history -r
:::0+update_terminal_cwd
bash: update_terminal_cwd: command not found
:::1+__git_ps1
bash: __git_ps1: command not found`

Comment: Are you sure you ran it **exactly** as-given, on a single line with the single-quotes on the assignment? If you used double-quotes instead, that would have expanded the values before running the new shell, resulting in the output given. And you said you had aliases in `.bash_rc` -- I don't see any aliases in your output above.

Comment: Yep, you are right. I am using a new mac and copied the bashrc file from my previous laptop(via email attachment for which I renamed _.bashrc_ to _bash\_rc_ so that it will appear in finder and then I just appended `.` to it after I have downloaded it on my new mac) . After which I was tinkering a bit with it and was using `source ~/.bash_rc` . That's the reason for the aliases to work. The aliases were not working when I opened a new tab. Sorry for my stupid question but I did learn a lot from your input about bash and hard links. Thanks! :)